# How to generate (where to look up) "always true" predicates of the form $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}:4x^2 + 4 \bmod 19 \neq 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, modular-arithmetic

> How to generate (where to look up) "always true" predicates of the form $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}:4x^2 + 4 \bmod 19 \neq 0$?

I'm doing a project, where I need some **always true** predicates of the form above. The project involves obfuscation of a program.

How would I generate such inequalities (or equalities) dynamically?

Also, could you recommend a good source which list a large number of such modular expressions?

Comment: There are lots of these. For example, if $p$ is a prime $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$ and $a,b,c$ have the property that $b^2-ac+1$ is divisible by $p$, then $ax^2+2by+c\not\equiv 0\pmod p$.

Comment: I'm interested in those that hold for all x :-)

Comment: It's true for all $x$. given $a,b,c$ that satisfy this condition. For example, if $p=11$ and $a=1$ and $b=2$ and $c=5$ then $x^2+4x+5\not\equiv 0\pmod{11}$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews. Do you know of a good ressource listing such invariant predicates?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - Shouldn't the $y$ be an $x$?

Answer (score 0):

We want to find $a,b,c$ such that $a x^2 +b x+ c \not= 0 \mod p$ and $a \not=0 $.

Let $x=y-\frac{b}{2a}$ and because fractions can be transformed into integers $\mod p$ (simply be multiplying inverse of the fraction, for example $\frac{1}{2} \mod 7 = 4$ . $\frac{1}{2}$ is fraction but $4$ is integer).

We arrive at $-\frac{b^2}{4 a}+a y^2+c \not= 0 \mod p$ which means that $a y^2 \not= \frac{b^2}{4a}-c \mod p$ divide by $a$ , we reach $y^2 \not= \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2} \mod p$ which just means that $\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$ quadratic non-residue $\mod p$ and $a \not=0 \mod p$. because $\frac{1}{4a^2}$ is quadratic residue $\mod p$, we just want that $b^2-4ac$ to be quadratic non-residue $\mod p$ which using Legendre symbol means that $(b^2-4ac)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = -1 \mod p$.

A good algorithm to do that is start with $k=1$, if $k^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = -1 \mod p$ then stop (if not add one to $k$, and repeat same process).

After finding such $k$, give some value for $b$ and for other variable $a$ or $c$ and then you will have $b^2-4ac = k \mod p$ which is one equation with one unknown.

Example : let $p=37$ now we start with the algorithm ($k^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \mod p$)

$k=1$ => $1^{18} = 1\mod 37$ => does not work.

$k=2$ => $2^{18} = -1 \mod 37$ => it works and we stop.

Now give some value for $b$ , i will give the value $b=3$.

Now give some value for $a$ or $c$, i will give the value $a=7$.

Now i need to solve $b^2-4ac = k \mod p$ => $3^2-4*7*c= 2 \mod 37$

Solving for $c$ using Euclid algorithm or any other known algorithm yields that $c=28$

Which then becomes $7x^2+3x +28 \not= 0 \mod 37$ (Checking using Wolfram Alpha).

Note : the algorithms and subjects used from the start of the answer are :

1 - [Quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue)

2 - [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol)

3 - [Modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)

4 - [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)